# request-promise: set timeout for long requests

Tags: javascript, timeout, requestjs, request-promise

I am using [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) library and trying to set the timeout as milliseconds as per their [documentation](https://github.com/request/request#timeouts). I have few requests on the server side that take more than a minute to response, no matter what value I set for timeout, the request always times out after a minute. What is the correct way to set read timeout in request?

My request

```
rp({
  uri: "http://something.com/long_running_request",
  timeout: 180000
})
```

Comment: There are two timeouts, one for the whope request (which you set) and another timeout nodejs will throw if the server does not respond early. So this is actually a server error as the server should at least answer with an empty package when the data comes in.

Comment: `Note that if the underlying TCP connection cannot be established, the OS-wide TCP connection timeout will overrule the timeout option` from the docs